# Proper controller action link syntax using slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my view, I have:

```
= form_for CustomerInfo.new  do |f|
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :first
      = f.text_field :first, maxlength: 50
    .form-group
      = f.label :last
      = f.text_field :last, maxlength: 50
    .actions = link_to "Save", :controller => :CustomerInfo, :action => :create
```

This causes a 500 error with no additional error information.

If I replace the last line with:

```
    .actions = f.submit 'Save'
```

Then the form renders fine.

Any idea why the original syntax is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting an error because the route you specified in the `link_to` does not exist.

**When you use the `:controller` option, you need to specify it in snake case and plural** (to match the plurality of the actual controller name).

So if your controller is named `CustomerInfosController`, you write that as `controller: :customer_infos`

Comment: I tried changing it to: .actions = link_to "Save", controller: :customer_infos, action: :create but I am getting a 404 error

Comment: What do the error logs say? Are you testing this in development mode? If so, there should be some more info about the specifics of the issue that would be helpful

Comment: I am not testing it in development mode. I am testing in test mode. I will see if I can get some more useful error info. It seems as if it fails as it enters the partial